# Get Min and Max for items from database using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

In database I have :

```
    Name         Value
    First Player   300
    First Player   500
    First Player   250
    SecondPlayer   200
    Second Player  450
```

And I need to show each player with max and min Values:

```
Name       MaxValue   MinValue
FirstPlayer   500        250
SecondPlayer   450       200
```

I did this:

```
var res = (from item in _context.Players
          select item).Max(s=>s.Value);
```

But Its only one player with max value;

Comment: You need to do group by player name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query syntax:

```
var result = (from item in _context.Players
group item by name into @group
select new 
{ 
    Name = @group.Key, 
    MaxValue = @group.Max(i=>i.Value), 
    MinValue = @group.Min(i=>i.Value)
}).ToList();
```

Or in a nice linq methods syntax: (This overload basically lets you to do the `.Select()` "in" the `.GroupBy()`

```
var result = _context.Players.GroupBy(item => item.Name, (key, @group) => new
        {
            Name = key,
            MaxValue = @group.Max(i => i.Value),
            MinValue = @group.Min(i => i.Value)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I find it really annoying when developers force themselves to use a keyword as a **variable** name that can be named anything ! And then uses @ to overcome a problem they created by themselves.People who designed the language syntax created @ for completely different cases.

Comment: @user3185569 - I agree but I'd also avoid using @group/grp/g all together and give a better name - this use is for explanatory reasons

Comment: The entity or complex type 'Context.Player' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.  I added select new Player , because In my view I have model Player.

Comment: @kirillnesterov - You should post a new question for this if you couldn't solve it through googling and trying

Answer (score 4):

GroupBy with Select should work:

```
var res = _context.Players.GroupBy(x=> x.Name)
                  .Select(x=> new 
                          { 
                                Name = x.Key, 
                                Max = x.Max(y=> y.Value), 
                                Min = x.Min(y=> y.Value) 
                          }).ToList();
```

Or using **Query-Syntax**:

```
var res = (from p in _context.Players
            group p by p.Value into grp
            select new
            {
                Name = grp.Key,
                Max = grp.Max(rec => rec.Value),
                Min = grp.Min(rec => rec.Value)
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: The entity or complex type 'Context.Player' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. I added select new Player , because In my view I have model Player.